# Cannot Fetch UIImage from URL

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am trying to fetch an image from URL, but i am not able to do it.
can any one let me know what went wrong

find the code below for your reference.

```
NSString *ImageURL = @"http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/TN/JacksonMadisonCounty/RoseHillMiddle/Uploads/Locations/{B690E93E-F7C9-48AF-B72A-BFF944FA6D4A}_104_9169.JPG";


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

  img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

where img is a UIImageView

Comment: Code looks like it should work (though, url is an unused variable).  My suspicion is that img is nil.  Can you NSLog(@"%@", img); before the last line.

Comment: @danh: yeh its nil, but if i open the url i have the image!!!!!

Comment: please leave comments for down voting, it helps me in future

Comment: agree with you that downvotes should be explained.  the nil img is your problem.  doesn't matter that the image loads on the web, it's loading in your code too, but then you're trying to display it in a non-existant part of the ui.

Comment: Why are you making the `url` object if you're not even going to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i just create DEMO of Your ImageURL you just Need to put Code Bellow:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *ImageURL = @"http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/TN/JacksonMadisonCounty/RoseHillMiddle/Uploads/Locations/{B690E93E-F7C9-48AF-B72A-BFF944FA6D4A}_104_9169.JPG";


    ImageURL =[ImageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"img url ==%@",ImageURL);
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
    UIImage *MYimage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    NSLog(@"==%@",MYimage);
    [imgview setImage:MYimage];

}
```

Download the Demo i just created of your image URL:-

http://www.sendspace.com/file/m966ae

Thank you :)

Comment: how can we do the same in android

Comment: in android you can do with replace { with %7b and replace } with %7d

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have "{" and "}" in your imageURL so you are not able to get your image, so just replace this braces.

```
-(NSString*)replace:(NSString*)string
{
    NSString *str = [[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@"%7B"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@"%7D"];

    return str;
}
```

Comment: can you explain why replacingOccurrencesofString... ?

Comment: i suspected this, too, but i copied the url into a browser and it loads.

Comment: now try bro. you are getting problem because you have { and } in your url, and you know that when we have spaces in url then we put %20, so in this case we will put %7B and %7D, if you are not getting my point then just paste your ImageURL in browser and then hit, then check url in address bar.. @NitinGohel , this will replace occurrence of particular string in our string with other string

Comment: No Need to replacing { to %7 you just need to put this :- `[ImageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

Comment: @NitinGohel -> actually i was using this method previously but i got problem with this,  just try to parse this url using your code.....     http%3A%2F%2Fwww.drinkbin.com%2Fimages%2Fdeals%2Fulj0w6tt4gu0i7ijqyts.jpg

Comment: @PradeepKumar -> use Nitin's code but make remember my code if you got any problem in future , just hit your url in browser and check new URL in addressBar

Answer (score 0):

Try this.......

```
NSString *ImageURL = @"http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/TN/JacksonMadisonCounty/RoseHillMiddle/Uploads/Locations/{B690E93E-F7C9-48AF-B72A-BFF944FA6D4A}_104_9169.JPG";
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
UIImage *IMG = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
img.image = IMG;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your url object in the following way :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ImageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

then use that url to fetch data. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to get Image from Url. you can use anyone.  but the fastest one that i have tried is

```
-(UIImage*)getImageFromURLwithUrl:(NSString*)imgURLStr
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithBodyParams = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURLStr]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestWithBodyParams returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return image;
}
```